# How do I check for divisibility in C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

recently I have been building a 2D game in the Unity game engine, but I am having some issues with getting the divisibility to work. I am new to the community so the code might be messy. In the if statement on Line 7 I have attempted to check for divisibility, but it doesn't seem to work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public Vector3 desiredPostion;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 divisible = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    
    if (1 == 1){
        Vector3 desiredPostion = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0f);
    }   

    transform.position = desiredPostion;
}
```

}

Comment: When inside the if, your "desiredPosition" is outside the scope of the rest of the Update() method.

Comment: As Kamalen says, and just to remark how to fix it, your if should look like: if (1 == 1){
desiredPostion = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0f);
    } (notice that I remove the "Vector3" inside the if.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `desiredPosition` twice, remove the second one:

```
public Vector3 desiredPostion;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 divisible = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (1 == 1)
    {
       desiredPostion = new Vector3
       (
           Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, 
           Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0f
       );
    }   

    transform.position = desiredPostion;
}
```

Comment: Like author said, when you declare Vector3 desiredPosition in local scope it hides the field "Vector3 desiredPosition" and also, the local "Vector3 desiredPosition" is only available within if brackets, so after leaving the brackets the local Vector3 desiredPosition do not exist any more, so 
transform.position = desiredPosition takes your field Vector3 desiredPosition that is never getting changed (because inside brackets you create new Vector3 desiredPosition that is being destroyed before script comes to your assignment at the end